# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method

Tags: java

I have searched for this problem and found many answers regarding it but however i did not understand them , i would a clarification regarding my own code so hopefully it will makes sense

i am trying to call the PrintList method in the main method

but i get this error

Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method PrintList() from the type Stack

if i change the modifier of PrintList to static , it ruins the whole code.

can anyone help me fix this issue please?

Thanks

```
public class Stack<Item> {


    public int N; // size of the stack
    public Node<Item> first; // top of stack
    public Node<Item> last; // top of stack

    // helper linked list class
    private static class Node<Item> {
        private Item item;
        private Node<Item> next;
    }

    public Stack() {
        first = null;
        last = null;
        N = 0;
    }

    public void PrintList() {
        Node<Item> current;
        current = first;
        while (current.next != null) {
            System.out.println(current.item);
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declare the stack

        Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();
        s.push("Bob");
        s.push("Mary");
        s.push("David");
        s.InsertBegin("George");
        System.out.println("First item: " + s.peek());
        Object current;
        PrintList(); // what is wrong here?
    }

}
```

Comment: @KickButtowski - it's the very last line (not counting the closing braces) where he/she calls `PrintList()`.

Comment: `Object current` doesn't do anything? In JAVA it's convention to name methodes like this: `printList()` so with a starting lowercase.

Comment: Next time when you ask a question, try to reduce the problem. Minimize the amount of code and if you still have the same error post that minimum amount of code, instead of pages of code.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are not specifying the instance that `PrintList` is to be called on. To fix that, change this:

```
        PrintList(); // what is wrong here?
```

to this:

```
        s.PrintList();
```

Comment: @user3650636 Ruakh's answer is correct - please see my answer for *why* it's correct.

Answer (score 3):

What you really need is to understand exactly what `static` and `non-static` actually mean.

First, some background. Apologies if some of this is already familiar to you. Java is an [object oriented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) language, you create a `class` to act as a template for a specific type of object, defining what *attributes* (variables) that it has, and *how it behaves* (methods). These attributes and behaviours *belong to objects of that class*:

```
public class Person {
    private String forename;
    private String surname;

    public Person(String forename, String surname) {
        this.forename = forename;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return forename + " " + surname;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person john = new Person("John", "Doe");
    }
}
```

The above code defines a template for creating objects of the type `Person`, each having a `forename` and a `surname`, both of the type `String`. It also defines a behaviour that allows you to get a `Person`'s full name using the `getFullName()` method.

Both `forename` and `surname`, as well as `getFullName()` are examples of `non-static` fields/methods. That is, *they belong to a specific Person object*. Importantly: **none of these can exist without a `Person` object being created first**. In this case we have a `Person` object called `john` which has a `forename` of "John" and a `surname` of "Doe". If we were to call `john`'s `getFullName()` method:

```
john.getFullName();
```

Then we'd get `"John Doe"` back.

The opposite of this is `static`. Static things *do not belong to an object*, instead, they *belong to a `class`*.

```
public class Person {
    private String forename;
    private String surname;

    private static String species = "Homo sapiens";

    public Person(String forename, String surname) {
        this.forename = forename;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return forename + " " + surname;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person john = new Person("John", "Doe");
    }
}
```

Here the `String` `species` *doesn't* belong to `john`, it belongs to `Person`. Static methods and variables **don't need an object in order to exist, they always* exist**. You access it by using the `class` itself as a reference, like this:

```
Person.species;
```

In your example, you have defined a method `PrintList()` as a *behaviour* of objects of the `Stack<Item>` class. The problem is that you're inside the `main` method, which is `static`. This means that you aren't in the 'context' of an object (because `main` belongs to `Stack<Item>`, **not objects of the type `Stack<Item>`**) when you're trying to call the `PrintList()` method. When you're inside a `static` method, in order to call a `non-static` method or access a `non-static` attribute, you **must** do so using a reference *to an object of the class that owns it*. In your case, you already have this reference in the form of `s`, so you can call your `PrintList()` method like so:

```
s.PrintList();
```

NB: Conventionally in Java we use camelCase for method names, so it really should be `printList()`.

When I first started to learn Java, I found the concept of `static` very difficult to wrap my head around - because I hadn't learned to think in an object-oriented way yet. When the penny drops, you'll wonder why you ever struggled with it. Hopefully this will help you get closer towards that penny-drop moment!

*As long as the class is loaded and it's not a compile-time constant (but you don't need to worry about those yet).

Comment: Really comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can call static methods like this:

```
ClassName.methodToCall();
```

You can call non-static methods like this:

```
ClassName classInstance = new ClassName();
classInstance.methodToCall();
```

Since your method `PrintList()` is non-static as it should be in this case, you should call it on an instance.