# non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context while passing between classes

Tags: java, csv

I know this was asked so many times but I can't get the grasp of it.
I have this method:

```
public static void toFile() throws FileNotFoundException{
    PrintWriter oFile = new PrintWriter("Output.csv");
    oFile.println("Tipas,Vadovas,Pavadinimas,Produktas(MB),Darbuotojai(UAB)");
    Company Com = companyList.get(companyList.size()-1);
    Company.csv(Com, oFile);
    oFile.close();
}
```

On the line `Company.csv(Com, oFile);` I get error `non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context`

csv method looks like this

```
public void csv(Company Com,PrintWriter oFile){
       oFile.print("Kita");
       oFile.println(b+","+n+","+","+"-"+","+"-"); 
   }
```

As I understood I should have instance variables when passing but I think I can't do this (am I right?)

*NOTE: Company class have two child classes with csv method. Don't know if this helps.

Comment: The other questions answer this well enough. In short, you cannot access instance methods without an instance!

Comment: user3580294 I do understand this but how to make them instance?

Comment: Same way you make an instance for any other object -- `<static_type> <variable_name> = new <constructor>(....);`

Comment: Currently your `csv` method is an *instance* method. The problem is that by prefixing the call to it with the class name (`Company` in your case), you're specifying that you want to call a `static` method in the `Company` class called `csv`. I posted an explanation of `static` vs `non-static` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23860661/cannot-make-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-method/23860891#23860891) that you might find useful if you're struggling with the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you actually want is to change this:

```
Company Com = companyList.get(companyList.size()-1);
Company.csv(Com, oFile);
```

to this:

```
Company Com = companyList.get(companyList.size()-1);
Com.csv(oFile);
```

and then change the `csv` method to this:

```
public void csv(PrintWriter oFile){
```

I think this is correct because the `csv` method is printing out instance variables that are contained within the `Com` instance -- am I right?

Comment: The oFile is the main problem here. I did as you wrote but the error is the same

Comment: If you get rid of `Company.csv(Com, oFile)` and replace it with `Com.csv(oFile)`, then you should no longer see that error.

Comment: Oh missed that bit. Thanks it works, but can you give a little bit more information on why this works? I want to understand it clearly.

Comment: In your example, you have a class called `Company` and one _instance_ of that class.  You called the instance `Com`.  In reality, you could have many more instances, such as `com1`, `com2`, etc, and each instance would have its own copy of the variables (it appears you have `n` and `b` as variables.  Originally, you were trying to invoke the `toFile()` method on the `Company` class, but the `Company` class doesn't have access to the actual values of the `Com` instance: instead, the `Company` class simply defines what the variable names and types are.